# load wordpress locally after uploading files to ftp

Tags: wordpress, ftp, host

hello I am new to hosting websites and have a question. So I want to host a wordpress website and created an ftp account. Using filezilla, I added my files to the account. When I look at my file manager I can see that the files have been uploaded. I wanted to now try using some type of url to see the website. The way the file path is in my ftp is

```
public_html/test/test1/1839583
```

and inside 1839583 I have folders like wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes. How can I run this website locally so I can see this website on chrome?